# Running protractor with Genymotion Android emulator "this.shell(...).trim" persists through multiple versions of uiautomator

Tags: android, protractor, appium, genymotion

Hey guys when I try running a protractor test suite on Appium 1.6 using a genymotion Android emulator I am getting stuck on this line.

```
[ADB] Error: Unable to get pids for tomator2.server. Orginial error: this.shell(...).trim is not a function
```

that is the uiautomator2 and,

```
[ADB] Error: Unable to get pids for uiautomator. Orginial error: this.shell(...).trim is not a function
```

for uiautomator v1

I've googled hard for a few hours and found nothing. The Original error is the same for both so I'm wondering if there is a dependency I am missing?

Full appium output:

```
   [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"browserName":"chrome","a...
[Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   browserName: 'chrome'
[Appium]   appium-version: '1.6.0'
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '6.0'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'Android Emulator'
[Appium]   nativeInstrumentsLib: true
[Appium]   count: 1
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: appium-version, nativeInstrumentsLib, count.
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 7a168bff-2f5f-4cb9-9e88-e73233952421
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting Java version
[AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_101
[AndroidDriver] We're going to run a Chrome-based session
[AndroidDriver] Chrome-type package and activity are com.android.chrome and com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[ADB] Using adb from /Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[debug] [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[AndroidDriver] Looking for a device with Android '6.0'
[debug] [ADB] Setting device id to 192.168.56.102:5555
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","shell","getprop","ro.build.version.release"]
[AndroidDriver] Using device: 192.168.56.102:5555
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[ADB] Using adb from /Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb
[debug] [ADB] Setting device id to 192.168.56.102:5555
[AndroidDriver] App file was not listed, instead we're going to run com.android.chrome directly on the device
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Checking whether package is present on the device
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","shell","pm","list","packages","com.android.chrome"]
[AndroidDriver] Starting Android session
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","wait-for-device"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","shell","echo","ping"]
[debug] [Logcat] Starting logcat capture
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","install","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/io.appium.settings/bin/settings_apk-debug.apk"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","install","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-unlock/bin/unlock_apk-debug.apk"]
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","shell","getprop","ro.build.version.release"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[AndroidDriver] Screen already unlocked, doing nothing
[AndroidDriver] No app sent in, not parsing package/activity
[debug] [AndroidDriver] No app capability. Assuming it is already on the device
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Running fast reset (stop and clear)
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","shell","am","force-stop","com.android.chrome"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","shell","pm","clear","com.android.chrome"]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Watching for bootstrap disconnect
[debug] [ADB] Forwarding system: 4724 to device: 4724
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","forward","tcp:4724","tcp:4724"]
[debug] [UiAutomator] Starting UiAutomator
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'starting'
[debug] [UiAutomator] Parsing uiautomator jar
[debug] [UiAutomator] Found jar name: 'AppiumBootstrap.jar'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/Users/ericsavoie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.102:5555","push","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-bootstrap/bootstrap/bin/AppiumBootstrap.jar","/data/local/tmp/"]
[debug] [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[debug] [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] Error: Unable to get pids for uiautomator. Orginial error: this.shell(...).trim is not a function
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:441:9)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
    at Promise.F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
    at ADB.callee$0$0 [as getPIDsByName] (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:431:18)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:448:27)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
    at Promise.F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
    at ADB.callee$0$0 [as killProcessesByName] (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:453:17)
    at UiAutomator.killUiAutomatorOnDevice$ (lib/uiautomator.js:90:22)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
    at Promise.F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
    at UiAutomator.killUiAutomatorOnDevice (lib/uiautomator.js:88:33)
    at UiAutomator.start$ (lib/uiautomator.js:29:18)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
 Error: Unable to get pids for uiautomator. Orginial error: this.shell(...).trim is not a function
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:441:9)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
    at Promise.F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
    at ADB.callee$0$0 [as getPIDsByName] (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:431:18)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:448:27)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
    at Promise.F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
    at ADB.callee$0$0 [as killProcessesByName] (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:453:17)
    at UiAutomator.killUiAutomatorOnDevice$ (lib/uiautomator.js:90:22)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:185:17)
    at Promise.F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:209:12)
    at UiAutomator.killUiAutomatorOnDevice (lib/uiautomator.js:88:33)
    at UiAutomator.start$ (lib/uiautomator.js:29:18)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[ADB] Error: Unable to kill uiautomator processes. Original error: Unable to get pids for uiautomator. Orginial error: this.shell(...).trim is not a function
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:457:9)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
 Error: Unable to kill uiautomator processes. Original error: Unable to get pids for uiautomator. Orginial error: this.shell(...).trim is not a function
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:457:9)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[UiAutomator] Error while killing uiAutomator: Error: Unable to kill uiautomator processes. Original error: Unable to get pids for uiautomator. Orginial error: this.shell(...).trim is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution. Install the latest node

[Node 6.9.1](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

And try to run test case. If you still face the issue, Run the following command in command prompt

```
npm install -g appium --no-shrinkwrap
```